# reset rad studio settings without uninstalling it

Tags: delphi

I use Delphi xe7 update 1 and I noticed something weird today with the code editor. the ide starts typing from another position instead of my current cursor position. I don't have any ide enhancement tools installed. is there anyway I can reset rad studio settings to default without uninstalling it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can't think of any editor setting that would cause that behavior.

Any kind of reset is going to clear all of the changes to the IDE configuration, including uninstalling all third-party components.

The easiest way to find out what's causing it is to edit the shortcut that starts Delphi and add the `-r foo` command line switch. This tells the IDE to use a different registry entry (in this case, `foo`); since the registry key doesn't exist, the IDE will create it using the default entries exactly as it did the first time you started the IDE.

You can then either use RegEdit to compare the code editor settings between the two keys, or export the one from `foo`, edit the resulting `.reg` file to change the key name to the actual key, and import that reg file to replace the existing values with the new ones from `foo`.

Note that `foo` is just an example name. You can use any name for the new registry key; `foo` is the one usually chosen, because it's easy to remember and find later to delete to keep your registry clean.

Once you're done, don't forget to edit the shortcut again to remove the `-r foo` switch.

Comment: awesome suggestion. thanks. I did what you suggested and used beyond compare to get their differences, I then figured out that the insert option in the editor was set to false.

Comment: More on the command line switch option here: http://support.embarcadero.com/article/42597

Answer (score 1):

cleanregistryide

Clean the registry entries for the IDE. Deletes the BDS current user registry key and files under appdata in the BDS directory. Caution: You will lose all your projects from the BDS directory, so back them up before starting BDS with this option. This is a last resort, not the first thing you should try when troubleshooting the IDE.

any installed components will not get uninstalled but will no longer be loaded.