# list out of bounds(108) error in delphi 10 seattle new component wizard

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle

When I try to use the new components wizard, I get the error "**list out of bounds(108)**" when the list of basic components is about to be loaded.
I get out of this error normally by restarting the IDE and all is well, how ever this time it is not the case.

I get these errors when I close the IDE.

**1)** **System error code 1400, invalid window handle.**

**2)** **an AV in module 'rtl230.bpl'.**

Also sometimes I get **'invalid pointer'** but the list is loaded.

**Does any one know about this or how it is solved?**

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I'm not sure I'm following you. What do you mean?

Comment: You are reporting a bug in a piece of software. We are not the developer of the software. Report the bug to the developer.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan okay that is fair to say thank you

Comment: @JerryDodge you are right. that big is indeed confusing.

Comment: Start the IDE with the `-rFoo` command line switch. This loads it with no third party tools and the default components only. Does the error still happen with that configuration? If so, it's an IDE bug and should be reported to EMBT. If not, it's an issue with a third-party component or wizard or IDE expert, and you'll have to start installing them one at a time to see which one is causing the problem.

Comment: Addition to my previous comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29847946/62576) for a description of what `-rFoo` means and does, and more specifics about how to use it.

Comment: @KenWhite I will try and report, thanks it is a good idea

Comment: @KenWhite unfortunately I'm trying to reproduce the bug again with and without your idea but it is gone. next time I encounter it I will try your idea thanks again for the suggestion. till then I will leave the question open