# Delphi IDE stuck on "Opening project" dialog

Tags: delphi, rad-studio

I have encountered a problem while trying to open demo projects for the TMS FNC WX component in Delphi, which I installed using the GetIt package manager. The installation itself went smoothly, but when I attempt to open the demo projects, I find myself stuck in an infinite "opening project" dialog loop. To illustrate the issue, I have attached a screenshot:
[image: opening project dialog]

During this time, the IDE remains responsive, but no matter how long I wait, the dialog doesn't disappear. When I eventually decide to close the project, I see the code for the demo, and the "opening project" dialog is replaced with another dialog:
[image: Save project dialog]

If I select "No" in response to the save prompt, the project simply closes. However, if I click "Cancel," the "opening project" dialog reappears, and the code for my project appears to load in the background. While the IDE remains technically functional, the presence of the "opening project" dialog blocks me from executing any actions.

I attempted to resolve the issue by changing the properties of the .dpr file, specifically the "open with" setting, from bdsLauncher.exe to bds.exe. This appeared to temporarily fix the problem, allowing me to open a demo project that was previously stuck in the "opening project" dialog loop. However, this workaround only worked once, and now switching between bdsLauncher.exe and bds.exe doesn't resolve the issue anymore.

It's worth noting that I can open other projects (non-demos) without any problems. I've also inspected the .dpr files of both projects that open successfully and those causing the "opening project" dialog loop, but I couldn't identify any differences.

Reinstalling the Rad studio or the component seems like my last option, and I'd like to avoid it if possible due to the inconvenience it would cause. If anyone has encountered a similar issue or has suggestions for a solution, I would greatly appreciate your assistance.

Comment: From your description it seems you are opening this projects by double-clicking on a DPR or DPROJ file. What happens if you try to open such project from the Delphi IDE itself? Some older versions of Delphi experienced some issues while opening projects by double-clicking and not from IDE. Most notable was IDE getting stuck in Debug mode even when Debug session ended.

Comment: I had a similar issue at some point, turns out the issue was a custom component class was stuck in a loop. Check what controls/components could cause this issue.

Comment: @SilverWarior yes I have tried your suggestion as well. Makes no difference if I open it through the .dpr file directly or through the ide.

Comment: @Codex did you just reinstall the components? How should I go about this?

Comment: Try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29847946/62576) for a way to temporarily disable all third-party components and IDE wizards/plugins for troubleshooting purposes.

Comment: @Merkdon You can disable certain packages, which are a suite of components, from the Component -> Install packages menu. You can try disabling components that you see are used in the project.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the suggestions, everyone, and a special thanks to @Codrut for their comment: 'I had a similar issue at some point; it turns out the issue was caused by a custom component class stuck in a loop.' It appears that I had an older version of the TMS components that I had previously downloaded from the GetIt package manager. After removing the old component and instead downloading the trial version from TMS's official website, which provided an up-to-date version of the components, everything now works perfectly. So, the issue was not related to the IDE or any other factors; it was indeed caused by the components themselves, which caused the infinite 'opening project' loop.